# Rebound: fatal error while opening a file

Tags: c, runtime-error, simulation, physics, integrator

I am using a software called Rebound which is a type of N-body integrator that generates simulations according to a certain code I wrote. the software uses built in functions of  its own which are based on C.

part of the code I wrote is when I'm telling the program to output certain data into separate text files every set period of time.

```
 char array [1000000];
 if (reb_output_check(r, 49.581410)){
   sprintf(array, "output%d.txt", i);
   i++;
   reb_output_orbits(r, array );     //output the orbital elements
  }
```

the reb_output_check function checks whenever the time is a multiple of 49.581410 years in simulation r to execute the rest.

everything is working out fine until the 252nd output where the simulation stops and this appears:

Fatal error! Exiting now. Can not open file

I've repeated the simulation more than once and I'm getting the same thing at the same time every time. I don't know why it's giving me this.

any help regarding the matter is much appreciated.

Comment: How can we possibly know what the problem is with such incomplete information? The problem could be anywhere from line 0 to line 999999 in your code and you think we can tell what the problem is from seeing 6 lines of your code? There is no shortcut - you'll have to use a debugger and/or other standard debugging techniques to track the problem.

Comment: I already tried to see where the problem is. when I remove this part of the code, then the problem is resolved, so the problem is somewhere here I guess. plus the code is long,  I cant post it all here...

Comment: For starters, find where in the code `Fatal error! Exiting now. Can not open file` comes from and work back from there.

Comment: it's in this part of the code!!

Comment: It may or may not be in this code. Just because you remove some code and the symptoms change is not a definite indication that this code is the root cause of the problem. That is something most experienced programmers know. So it is impossible to help you with this incomplete information. Can't you understand that we would be magicians if we could debug your whole program by seeing these 6 lines of code? Maybe your disk is full. Maybe you've called the function that this code is in recursively leading to a stack overflow. etc. The possibilities are endless.

Comment: I've added my main function. I hope it helps, and please ask if there's something vague. sorry for not being clear before

Comment: Are you perhaps leaving your output files open, and running out of file handles? What is the output of `ulimit -n` on your workstation? What happens if you increase the limit (or decrease it) -- does the error occur at another time? If you run `lsof` on your running process it can show you the open handles.

Comment: thank you..that might be the case, ill try it out

Comment: `char array [1000000];` is a very large space for just a filename. Maybe it just doesn't fit in automatic storage. (*the stack*)

Comment: @gilez as you said the problem was with leaving the files open, I decreased the number to see what happens at I got the same error at the value I put. I upped it again to fix it. decreased the size of the char array as well. thank you all!!